# writing multiple excel sheets into one for loop code

Tags: python, dataframe

```py
sheet1=[FC_filter1,FC_filter2,FC_filter3]

with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    FC_filter1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FC_filter1',index='False')
    FC_filter2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FC_filter2',index='False')
    FC_filter3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FC_filter3',index='False')
```

Can we make this code into one line using for loop instead of mentioning FC_filter1,2,3 each time ?

Comment: I'm not an expert in PANDAS,  but since you are opening the Excel document in 'a' mode, there should be no problem doing something like `for sheet_filter in sheet1: with pd.ExcelWriter...`. The only problem is that you don't have an array of sheet titles. There is no clean way in python to convert variable identifier to string. Instead, put the strings into another array. ["FC_filter1","FC_filter2","FC_filter3"].

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop through `sheet1` with enumerate to name the sheets counting up, starting by 1. This assumes that the names of your filter going like 1,2,3,... If not, you could save the data as dictionary with the name as key (string) and the df as value and access them in a for loop.

```py
sheet1=[FC_filter1,FC_filter2,FC_filter3]

with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    for i, fc in enumerate(sheet1, 1):
        fc.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'FC_filter{i}',index='False')
```

Comment: It is taking fc as string,I'm getting this error,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Comment: do you have a df which is stored as variable `FC_Filter1`?

Comment: final_dict = dict(zip(sheet1, list(new.values())))
locals().update(final_dict)

I'm storing keys of dic as variable- FC_filter 1,2,3

Comment: this is different from the list `sheet1` your provided in your question... please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73254987/edit) your code so we have all information we need.

Comment: with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    for m, fc in enumerate(sheet1, 1):
            pd.DataFrame(result[0]).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'FC_filter{m}',index='False')

Insteading of giving result[0], can we automate this with len()?